# Элемент не подстраивается под контент в нём

Tags: html, css

Верстал , верстал тут чат и вот , проблема , width не подстраивается под текст в сообщении , в отличии от height . Объясните в чём ошибка и как её исправить . Вот код css

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.section_type3 {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 27px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.my_message_section p {
  color: #fff;
}

.section_type3 p {
  margin: 0;
}

.my_message_section {
  background-color: #465bfa;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.message_section {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
}

@media not all and (orientation:portrait) {
  .my_message_section {
    margin-right: 500px;
  }
  .message_section {
    margin-left: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <section class="section_type3 message_section">
    <p class="type1_p">Здравствуй , я бот . Можешь написать мне "Помощь" и я покажу все доступные команды</p>
  </section>

  <section class="section_type3 my_message_section">
    <p class="type1_p">Помощь</p>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: Все работает , опишите детально проблему!

Comment: убери странные margin и все заработает

Comment: @JuniorCoder , запустите код и вы увидите что section под классом my_message_section ( синий элемент ) растянут . Нужно сделать так , что бы синее поле равномерно во все стороны облегало текст , то есть что бы отступы между правым , левым , нижним , верхним краем и текстом были одинаковыми

Comment: @Grundy , какие именно margin странные ? Я убрал все и всё осталось так же , кроме того что все элементы сдвинулись к левому боку страницы

Comment: @ДмитрийХватов, которые в `media`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как используются блочные элементы, они стремятся занять всю доступную ширину.

Чтобы ширина выставлялась по контенту нужно установить `display: inline-block`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.section_type3 {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 27px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.my_message_section p {
  color: #fff;
}

.section_type3 p {
  margin: 0;
}

.my_message_section {
  background-color: #465bfa;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.message_section {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
}

@media not all and (orientation:portrait) {
  .my_message_section {
    margin-right: 500px;
  }
  .message_section {
    margin-left: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <section class="section_type3 message_section">
    <p class="type1_p">Здравствуй , я бот . Можешь написать мне "Помощь" и я покажу все доступные команды</p>
  </section>

  <section class="section_type3 my_message_section">
    <p class="type1_p">Помощь</p>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: Но при добавлении элементу свойство display:inline-block; он перестаёт выравниваться по правому краю , как тогда выравнивать синие элементы, которые должны быть справа ?

Comment: @ДмитрийХватов, сейчас в примере два блока - один выровнен справа, другой слева

Comment: понял , просто нужно было добавить float:right; для my_message_section

Comment: @ДмитрийХватов, в сниппете не используются `float`,